# How can I extend primary partition into an extended partition's free space?

Tags: disk, partitioning, disk-management

I looked around but this question hasn't been asked before. My disk looks like this:

The 64 GB primary partition is Windows. I want to extend that into the 17GB (highlighted) free space. Is it possible to do so **without** wiping the whole extended partition?

[image]

Comment: `Is it possible to do so without wiping the whole extended partition?` Yep. It's possible . First you need to get out of that 17 GB free space from the extended partition.

Comment: Any one of the answers from [here](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=user:202806+[partitioning]) will help you.

Comment: Sorry to say but those answers didn't help...

Answer (score 0):

You need to shrink the **extended partition** by moving the starting point higher (toward the right).

Once you do this, you can grow partition 2 by extending the ending point to the right to take up the 17 GB free space that will now be outside the extended partition.

You should be able to do this without hurting existing partitions if you are careful and pay attention so you don't make mistakes (and if nothing unforeseen happens, such as a power failure or disk failure).

Comment: Backups are important especially because of the unforeseen events. Use gparted to shrink extended, but use Windows to expand the Windows partition and immediately reboot Windows so it can run chkdsk.